# How to mitigate CPU to GPU bottleneck

Tags: c#, opengl, gpgpu, point-clouds, compute-shader

I am using ComputeSharp library to run a compute shader on a very large set of data. The dataset is around 10GB, separated into smaller (about 3Gb) pieces for GPU to handle. The problem is that each piece takes about 1s to load, compute and return, even though the computation is almost instant.

I am looking for a way to speed this up, as now it gets outperformed by CPU in certain cases.

More details:
The dataset consists of custom points forming a point cloud. The shader is finding the points with highest values and using those to render an image. The max size of the point cloud will be about 500million points.

The points are already as small as they can be, saving all the metadata in a single int. Everything gets put in a buffer and passed to shader which spits out another buffer with result. I already tried and failed to use textures as they do not support custom types.

Edit (Minimal reproduction):

```
public struct DataPoint
{
    public float3 Position;
    public uint Value;
}

public void ComputeOneChunk(DataPoint[] dataPoints)
{
    var stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    using var currentChunk = _gpu.AllocateReadOnlyBuffer(dataPoints);
    stopWatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Buffering took {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    stopWatch.Restart();
    _gpu.For(dataPoints.Count, 1, new FindMax(
        currentChunk,
        resultBuffer));
    stopWatch.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Execution took {stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
}

[AutoConstructor]
public readonly partial struct FindMaxForWell : IComputeShader
{
    public readonly ReadOnlyBuffer<DataPoint> buffer;
    public readonly ReadWriteBuffer<uint> resultBuffer;

    public void Execute()
    {
        //DoStuff
    }
}
```

Comment: What exaclty is using most of the time in your current process ? Preparing the data to send to the GPU, or the transfer itself. If it's the former, maybe you are doing a little too much prepwork and some of it should be handled GPU side ? If it's the transfer itself ? What is the available bandwidth between your CPU and GPU (e.g. PCIe 3.0 X16 should be 16GB/s)

Comment: You can only read as fast at the file system allows.  Switching to a faster drive will help.

Comment: @Irwene The bulk of the time seems to be the transfer. Data is prepared separately with its own time measurement that is irrelevant here and for now I only have a synthetic dataset generator for testing. I am running on a 2070 MaxQ and I also tested on an Intel integrated GPU. The times were almost the same or sometimes smaller for the integrated gpu, which makes sense since it shares the memory with CPU in the first place. I will run some more tests to see what exactly takes the most time.

Comment: @jdweng The whole dataset is stored in RAM. I have 40GB(8 + 32, I know not ideal but I am not made of money) of RAM for this purpose, so drive speed is irrelevant.

Comment: Without seeing how you are loading it it's hard to give a good answer. The GPU should be able to use Direct Memory Access and bypass the CPU for loading, given the right instructions

Comment: Just verified it, ```using var chunk = _gpu.AllocateReadOnlyBuffer(dataPoints)``` takes 855ms while execution takes only 150ms.

Comment: @Charlieface See my previous comment for how I load the data into buffer.

Comment: @Luk164 can you please post some repro code?

Comment: Use task manager and check memory usage while running.  If memory usage is high than swapping map be occurring.  See if you can increase the memory in the machine.

Comment: Looking at the source code, there appears no way to create a `ReadOnlyBuffer` without allocating a new blob of memory.

Comment: @jdweng That was a problem on the previous machine, not on the 40GB one. This is between CPU-GPU bandwidth and memory allocation.

Comment: @Charlieface The repro is in the edit.

Comment: @Charlieface Tried separating allocation and loading of data, allocation alone took just 72ms.

Comment: If you have not done so already, could you perhaps test with a dramatically reduced size of your data point pieces (say for example a few dozen MBs), if that is possible? The idea behind this is to see whether the time taken for loading the data is related to or dependend on the the data size, or whether it is rather a fixed time cost.

Comment: Do we know if the issue is a latency issue (loading doesn't start immediately) or a running issue?  I wondering if another task is running with higher priority that is causing latency.  May be try increasing the priority of process to see what happens.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Yes I checked with smaller data and yes it was faster then, so clearly it points to the data size being a problem. I also found out about UploadBuffer class that is supposed to speed things up by removing an intermediate step.

Comment: @jdweng That does not seem to be the case, the CPU never even maxes out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. It seems that converting dataPoints array to a buffer takes a long time and involves some intermediate steps. To speed this up you can use UploadBuffer which eliminates these extra steps.

```
_currentChunk = _gpu.AllocateReadOnlyBuffer<DataPoint>(uploadBuffer.Length); 
_currentChunk.CopyFrom(uploadBuffer);
```

This changed 1s to around 300ms, which is probably as fast as it will ever go over PCIe.

Another problem appeared however, and that is that UploadBuffer uses Span and accessing it to save data is very slow, which I am still trying to solve.